# Connection between custom database and wordpress database

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I'm working on a custom web app, in which i need to fetch some information (like: `username`,`email`,`phoneNo`) from the existing wordpress database with the table named `"users"`. My concerns is that, how will i connect the two databases in order to be able to use (display) those data from a wordpress database into my custom web app?

Comment: you can export users from wordpress db using export plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/users-customers-import-export-for-wp-woocommerce/ ... then create you code in php for importing the file to your custom database

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have multiple connections to the same database.
2. You can have multiple users with access to the same database.
3. You can have multiple pages hosted on the same server.

I think you just have to start coding...

Comment: thank you, now all works fine, and succeeded to establish the connection